# Python web framework for relatively static pages

Tags: python, web

I'm looking for a good Python framework to develop a small application in.

Basically the application is something which could be done in Javascript (the user enters values into text boxes and calculates other values) but because of IP (this is academia) there has to be no way for anyone to determine how these values are calculated.

For now, databases/users/etc. are not required. I really want something like PHP as far as the templating system goes, but in Python instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

It's a popular 'microframework' and would be suitable for what you're looking for including a simple templating system.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend Bottle for simple tasks like this.

http://bottlepy.org/

It has a built-in template engine as well, or you could replace it with something like Jinja.

Comment: Both answers get my +1.  Both are very similar.  The one thing I really love about bottle for this type of task is the whole framework is one file.